# Can't see the line number in Firefox Console if the file name is too long

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, console, filenames

In the Firefox Console, for debugging JavaScript error messages, if the filename is too long on the right-hand side, then the line number seems to be hidden. Is there a way to fix this so that I can see the line number? When I click on the filename, it opens up the correct file to the correct line, so clearly it knows what the line number is, but it just refuses to show it to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.Such issue exists .I didn't find any fix to it but when we click on that error and again go to the error console, the line number starts showing up.The issue seems that firefox scrolling element has not been set properly.